# Remotely update web site and mobile application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, compact-framework, windows-ce

We have a system that includes a small PC with a website (developped in ASP.net 3.5 using VS 2010) and a SQL database, and some Windows CE 5.0 smart devices (running a homemade WinForm Compact Framework 2.0 software). Those systems are installed to many customers across the country.

Now, I need to be able to automatically update the website and the CE application remotely.

I developped a program that runs on the small PC and retrieve the files (by FTP) to be updated from a WebService in our office. The program executes the database scripts and copy the file to its intended destination locally.

Question: can we "packaged" the website to be deploy remotely? Having to copy every files to the remote PC is very cumbersome and not efficient.

Also: How can I update the software running on the smart device? IP addresses are unknown, they needs be on the DHCP without IP reservation, as we need to be able to hot-swap any devices without doing any configuration.

thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: Generally if you plan to update things remotely, you have to *plan* ahead of time. Now you may have to improvise.

Comment: Let's say I can retrieve the IP of the devices, how can I copy a file over the network to a Windows CE device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both scenarios, the de-centrailized PC servers and the Windows Mobile clients you should consider a Remote Management System.

There is normally no way to push a file onto a windows mobile device, except for having an 'agent' running on the devices (i.e. a ftp server, or a Mobile Device Management Agent (ie by SOTI MobiControl or others).

You may provide a link to a CAB file (a windows mobile installation package) either on the remote servers or better on one central server) and let the users pick that by clicking it in a HTML page.

Are all the Windows Mobile devices by the same vendor and are the same models? Some industrial devices have software agents pre-installed. Some industrial devices also support download/setup via scanning a barcode.

Comment: yes, devices are all Motorola Mk500 with Windows CE 5.0, connected to a Wifi network. I can programatically figure out the IP addresses of the devices, but I'm looking for a way to copy a file over the lan directly into the device. I will program an agent locally in the device to automatically replace the EXE and relaunch the software.

Comment: It looks like the MK500 does not support a built-in ftp server. There are options with 'Rapid Deployment Client' or AirBeam to deploy files onto the device, both need a server installed with the MDM software (see MK500 product ref guide). I think the easiest is to provide an installation cab on the web servers and let the users download and install this (with an ftp server and your agent).

Comment: Although this solution would be perfect, our customer don't want to pay the fee for those software, so I need to develop an homemade solution. So I made a FTP client on the device who download the new version of the EXE to update from a FTP server located on the small PC. It works. Now I need to find a way to replace the old EXE with the new one and relaunch the app...

Comment: If you are using a cab (with a custom setup dll) or a script (look for MortScript), you have to kill the exe, replace it and then relaunch it.

Comment: yes thanks, I did another program, started by the main, who takes care of killing the .exe, replace the files and restarting the software. it works fine. thanks.